# Can I create an Ionic library the same way I create an Angular library?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an Ionic library with a custom component, going by the file structure in my present ionic app, it seems to look like an angular app. Also, a few google searches on how to create a library in Ionic shows suggestions of creating angular library and linking it to the ionic project. Is this an official way, because I would like to achieve creating a component like I have below and use it in my ionic project.

```
 <custom-button-tag
    [customStyle]="{'font-size.px':14, 'color' : 'green', 'background-color' : 'coral'}"
    [clientName]="'bassey'" 
    [env]="'sandbox'" 
    [callback_url]="'www.my-webhook.com'"
    [products]="['auth', 'transactions', 'balance', 'income', 'identity']" (onClose)="somthing()"
    (onSuccess)="somthing()">
    Open Widget
  </custom-button-tag>
```